# CTE built from UNION running very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-8.0, union-all

I've put together a simplified version of a query I'm struggling with:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        num_serves_p1 AS num_serves, player_id_p1 AS player_id, location, date_
    FROM
        table1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        num_serves_p2 AS num_serves, player_id_p2 AS player_id, location, date_
    FROM
        table1
)
SELECT 
    id_, SUM(cte.num_serves)
FROM
    table1 AS t
        JOIN
    cte ON cte.player_id = t.player_id_p1
        AND cte.location = t.location
        AND cte.date_ < t.date_
WHERE 
    t.id_ = 12345
```

This currently takes over a minute to run for about a million rows.

If I chop out the second part of the `UNION_ALL` to give me:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        num_serves_p1 AS num_serves, player_id_p1 AS player_id, location, date_
    FROM
        table1 
)
SELECT 
    id_, SUM(cte.num_serves)
FROM
    table1 AS t
        JOIN
    cte ON cte.player_id = t.player_id_p1
        AND cte.location = t.location
        AND cte.date_ < t.date_
WHERE 
    t.id_ = 12345
```

Or the first part of the `UNION_ALL` to give me:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        num_serves_p2 AS num_serves, player_id_p2 AS player_id, location, date_
    FROM
        table1 
)
SELECT 
    id_, SUM(cte.num_serves)
FROM
    table1 AS t
        JOIN
    cte ON cte.player_id = t.player_id_p1
        AND cte.location = t.location
        AND cte.date_ < t.date_
WHERE 
    t.id_ = 12345
```

Then either of these queries run in under 0.1 seconds.

So I figure all my indexes are good but the issue lies in using `UNION_ALL`. Given the drastic difference in performance then my hunch is that in the first query the CTE loads all the rows in table1 (x2) whereas in the second and third queries the CTE only loads the rows required by the joins?

I realise that I could create two CTEs and simply add the results together however at some point I'm going to calculate fields that rely on a date ordered `UNION_ALL` CTE.

Any ideas on why I'm seeing the poor performance with the first query and what I might be able to do about it?

Quick final note: I haven't included all the usual table descriptions etc because this is really a pseudo query. I figured there'd be enough to go on as I've isolated the usage of `UNION_ALL` as being the likely issue. I'm also not sure how to generate sufficient data to illustrate the issue. Fingers crossed the above is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Optimizer is not smart enough with unions, joins, CTEs, to to propagate the "id=" all the way through.  Instead, it is evaluating each part of the `UNION`, creating a temp table with all those rows, and possibly building an index to help with the next step.

It may run even faster if you do the `SUM` for each table copy and then add them together.  (I can't even tell if that is a valid transformation, and the Optimizer won't even try it.)

**More**

```
AND cte.date_ < t.date_
WHERE 
    t.id_ = 12345
```

-->

```
AND cte.date < ( SELECT date_ FROM t WHERE id_ = 12345 )
```

Or, this might be better:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT date_ FROM t WHERE id_ = 12345 ) AS d
    JOIN ...  (( the other stuff ))
    WHERE cte.date_ < d.date_
```

**and more**

```
SELECT  
    (
        SELECT  SUM(num_serves)
            FROM  table1
            WHERE  player_id = this.p1_id 
    ) AS p1_prev_serves, 
    (
        SELECT  SUM(num_serves)
            FROM  table1
            WHERE  player_id = this.p2_id 
    ) AS p2_prev_serves
    FROM  table1 AS this
    WHERE  player_id IN (this.p1_id, this.p2_id)
      AND  this.game_id = 12345;
SELECT  SUM(num_serves) AS prev_serves
    FROM  table1 AS all
```

Comment: Thanks Rick. Couple of clarifications... i) What do you mean by "move the `id_` test all the way into the inner selects"? Put the `id_` field into the `UNION_ALL` selects? ii) How would I get rid of the CTE? I need a to be able to run operations on a date ordered union.

Comment: OK, moving `id_` was the wrong idea.  It seems that `date_` (for `12345`) is the critical part.  Maybe my addition helps.

Comment: Hi Rick. Tried this out. Had to add `join_field_p1` and `join_field_A` into the subquery in the `FROM` clause as the CTE needs to join to those. Sadly that didn't improve things. Just to check I hadn't introduced another issue I ran the reformatted query with the non `UNION_ALL` version of the CTE and this returned a result in 0.14 seconds.

Comment: I don't understand what the query is trying to do.  It feels overly complex.  Can you explain the query's goal?

Comment: Hi. I've changed the column names to make them a little more meaningful. The table contains details of tennis matches. In this simple example I'm looking to sum `num_serves` for all previous matches for player 1 in the match with an `id` of 12345. A player can be p1 or p2 hence the `UNION`. I could accomplish this by summing two sub queries however in the future I'm also going to need to build more complex date order dependent versions, e.g. winning streak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224788/mysql-winning-streak. So I need to create a `UNION` version that can be sorted by date

Comment: The winning streak version is very complicated and before I started on that I wanted to make sure I can get a simple version working in roughly the same way that the winning streak version will need to be built.

Comment: I added a bunch.

Comment: Hi Rick. I can't see any edits?

Comment: @Jossy - Oops.  Maybe now.

Comment: Thanks Rick - I've implemented this. I'll probably have to add another question when I get to the date ordered version...